# How to assign special functions into a toolbar action element from dictionary PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am taking the data from the excel file with pandas.

I created a dictionary which includes the same length of my excel data.  `mat_id_list`

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Chart")

        self.button_dir={i:[0,0] for i in range(len(mat_id_list))}

        # print(button_dir)

        toolbar = QToolBar("My main toolbar")
        
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        
        for i in range(len(mat_id_list)):
            
            self.button_dir[i][0]=QAction(mat_id_list[i],self)
            self.button_dir[i][1]=print_id(i)
            
            self.button_dir[i][0].triggered.connect(lambda :self.button_dir[i][1])
            
            toolbar.addAction(self.button_dir[i][0])

        print(self.button_dir)        
               
        # print((self.agroup). checkedId())

    def print_id(self,i):
        print(mat_id_list[i])
```

Toolbar method works great with loop to create Buttons on toolbar but i can not assign specific function with for loop into my buttons or action.(I dont know how to call object name on the toolbar)

[image]

Here down below:
I thought that, i can create second index to fill a function in dictionary element to call it later with the click action happens.

```
self.button_dir={i:[0,0] for i in range(len(mat_id_list))}
```

Related below:

```
 self.button_dir[i][0].triggered.connect(lambda :self.button_dir[i][1])
```

My Goal is to define functions into the buttons on the toolbar that will give me the result of my function.

```
def print_id(self,i):
   print(mat_id[i])
```

"i" is the index number in the for loop.

Comment: Edit: I tried more things but every time when i click the  toolbar object it returns None

Comment: `action = QAction(mat_id_list[i], self); action.triggered.connect(lambda x, i=i: self.print_id(i)); toolbar.addAction(action)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to @ekhumoro's advice:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Chart")

        toolbar = QToolBar("My main toolbar")
        
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        
        for i in range(len(mat_id_list)):
            
            action=QAction(mat_id_list[i],self)
            action.triggered.connect(lambda x, i=i:
                                     self.print_id(i))
            toolbar.addAction(action)

    def print_id(self,i):
        print(mat_id_list[i])
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```